# Is it bad practice to dynamically set/change event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to replace `confirm()` boxes with bootstrap modals for save/delete operations in a page.There is a button(call it action-button) for each of these operation which then triggers the respective modal. On clicking the confirm button on the modal,the respective function is triggered.

Instead of writing modals for each of these operations,I was thinking if I could use just one confirm modal and change the event handler when the "action-button" is clicked.
Like this:

`$("#confirm-button").attr('onclick',save_all());`

when `save_all` button is clicked.
Is it bad practice?And what are some alternatives to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think changing the event handler is a good choice as you should handle the previous *attached* handlers in order to avoids memory leak and weird behaviours.

A better approach could be defining a generic handler that will read from a *data* attribute on the DOM, what to do in case of confirmation.

The main part is that such handler should not been coupled with the working staff.

To achieve this you could define custom events that will be fired from your generic handler.

I mean something like:

```
function confirmAction(ev) {
    // you can save in the HTML the name of the proper event
    var whatEv = $(this).data('my-key');

    // Here you could fire a custom event.
    $(this).trigger(whatEv);
}
```

Last thing, as @trincot pointed, your code in the OP is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It will not even do what you intend, because you call `save_all` at the moment you set the attribute, and it will be the function's return value that is stored in the `onclick` attribute, converted to string if it is not yet a string. This most probably is not what you intended to do.

Even if the attribute value would be correct, it is not the best practice, because:

- That attribute value needs to be evaluated/parsed, which means you can get late syntax errors
- It replaces the previous value of the `onclick` attribute, which might be an undesired effect (although I understand in your case that is what you want)

Instead bind event handlers the jQuery way and make sure you don't call the function, but pass its reference:

```
$("#confirm-button").on('click', save_all);
```

If the purpose is to *replace* any previous click handler, then chain in an `off` call:

```
$("#confirm-button").off('click').on('click', save_all);
```

Comment: Yeah,I didn't mean to do that.